# How to link Master page to other web pages

Tags: master-pages

I have a master page created on VisualStudio using C#. Just wondering when creating other web pages how do I apply the master page to it? Thanks

Comment: When you add new webform you should be have a checkbox option to add master page

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the web pages - in the popup plese select the check box "Select Master Page"
Or Go to existing web pages directive and add the attribute masterpage and its file path change the path as like the below

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>
```